# Titles and axis limits to all subplots with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to print a 3x4 grid of histograms from a dictionary of dataframes. I want to set all of the histograms using the same x and y limits and give all the graphs unique titles. Code below prints all the histograms but the x and y lims and title only appear on the last graph.

```
nrows = 3
ncols = 4   
count = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols)
for i in ax:
    for axis in i:
        dl[count].hist(['hundreds'], bins=ten_bin, ax=axis)
        plt.title(files[count]+' hundreds')
        plt.xlim([0,9])
        plt.ylim([0,250])
        count+=1
```

Where dl is the dictionary of data frames and the files list is name of the CSV where the df derives from.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do `axis.set_title` etc instead of `plt.title`....

Comment: BTW, an `axis` and an `axes` are distinct things in matplotlib, confusingly, so we try an avoid using `axis` to refer to an `axes`.

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak you nailed it! Lots of fussing over that thanks again.